# Adding Offset to rows

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, coldfusion, bootstrap-5

I have this code to create my own "table" (I can't use a table as I need some more complex things later).

```
<div class="container">
    <cfloop index="x" from="1" to="5">  
        <div class="row d-none d-lg-flex py-2 fw-bold">
            <cfloop index="y" from="1" to="6">
                <div class="col-2 px-3">
                    <p>CONTENT</p>
                </div>
            </cfloop>
        </div>
        <hr>
    </cfloop>
</div>
```

Now I would like to move the whole construct 1 col to the left.
I could use "col-1" on the first one, but I need the first one to be 2 col, too.

Is that somehow possible?

I can't move the whole container, as I need other things inside it that stay at the correct position.

Comment: I don't understand the question.  This content is already left justified, as it is,  unless we're missing some larger context.

Answer (score 0):

In Bootstrap, you can use "offset" classes to shift to the right, skipping a visual output of a column.

```
<div class="row">
   <div class=".col-md-3 .offset-md-3">content</div>
</div>
```

In your case, assuming you're in a  block, you can do:

```
 <div class="col-2 px-3 #(x == 1 ? '.offset-md-1' : '')#">
```

That uses a "ternary" expression to output an additional class if your index/x is 1.

Comment: Actually, I might have mis-read your question.  I'll leave this here, though, in case that helps you solve your issue, though I'm sure it'll get marked down.